# Subversion best practices, ASP.NET C# Site WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, webforms

I have one question about how to handle a webform sites, i have many sites sharing aspx.cs codes but the only diference is the aspx and the .css and images ones, how to handle this it with svn its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you're question isn't totally clear, but it sounds like maybe you should be using [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) to share the .aspx.cs (code behind) files.

You can specify the different .css files in the distinct .aspx file markup.

Using svn externals will enable you to share the code behind.

Alternatively you could explicitly specify the code behind file in your aspx markup if you only wanted to have one physical .aspx.cs file.

Comment: Hi Tristan, i made a WebForm site, this site is the "framework", now i need to construct and maintain this "framework" for many sites, so basicly i have one code *.aspx.cs, but many sites with our *.aspx, this is 1-n, 1 code to many "views"

Comment: @waldecir , in that case you can  create a separate project dll right and you can use everywhere.

Comment: So I think you can either use the page comand on your .apsx.cs page to point othe commone .aspx.cs file like;

<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="../MyExternalCodeBehind.aspx.cs"

Or use an svn external to point it to where you want. This definitly isn't a hard problem to solve with correct usage of the CodeFile attribute or use of svn externals.

Comment: i have some concerns about externals: svn:externals have a lot of problems most of them are difficult to see, track and repair: see an example here

commits cannot span over externals(no atomic commits)
branches will not branch their externals(as you pointed out)
tags will not "freeze" their externals so latter builds may result in different/broken builds
merging and reeintegrate merge will not work on externals
If you use externals to point to other repositories, you will most of the time do not have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Im tring to use a structure with codebehind, its apers to be the best one.